# Generating Accèss Token- OAuth2.0

Tags: python, api, visual-studio-code, spotify

I am working with the Spotify API. I am trying to generate an access token. I followed along https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdq6Gz33khQ this video to generate the token.

I am getting an error

```
{'error': 'invalid_client'}
```

The code I have written is:

```
import base64
from wsgiref import headers
import requests
import json  

client_id = "09e0b9beeba74aee986546f496823d60"
client_secret = "be1c93f2a446477e8416235b2a3f442c"


# searching for token which will help in authorization

client_creds = f"{client_id} : {client_secret}"

client_creds_b64 = base64.b64encode(client_creds.encode())

token_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
method = "POST"
token_data = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}

token_header = { 
"Authorization" : f"Basic {client_creds}" # <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>
}

r = requests.post(token_url, data=token_data, headers=token_header)
print(r.json())
```

Not sure why I get this error. It could be the link I am using for the token url but can't find what to replace it with.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
client_creds = f"{client_id} : {client_secret}"
```

to

```
client_creds = f"{client_id}:{client_secret}"
```

change

```
"Authorization" : f"Basic {client_creds}" # <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>
```

to

```
"Authorization": f"Basic {client_creds_b64.decode()}"
```